# How to split function in two different class with inheritance? Beginner

Tags: python, function, class

I have a `json` like below. I have program also below.Need to divide the program in to `two` class. first get the request in `first class` and then do the operation in `second class`. Basically how to convert my function in to `two` separate classes where on class is general and other class do the operations

Postman accepts the json `POST` request as below  `http://127.0.0.1:5000/out`

```
{
    "filters": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "pool",
        "type": "str",
        "date": ["2019-12-01", "2019-12-03"]
    }]
}
```

Flask Code is below

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/out/', methods=[ 'POST'])   
def values_extract():
    json_request = request.get_json()
    start_date = ''
    end_date = ''
    data = json.loads(json.dumps(json_request))

   #if valid json then do the below program in separate `**class**`

    for i in data['filters']:
    if i['type'] == 'pool':
       start_date =  i['date'][0]
       end_date = i['date'][1]
    return  (start_date, end_date)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

My flask is perfectly running with above function

My psuedo code with class

```
class jsonrequest():
        def getrequest(self,json_request,data):
                self.json_request = request.get_json()
                self.data = json.loads(json.dumps(json_request))
                start_date = ''
                end_date = ''

class valuesextract(jsonrequest):
        def filtervalues(self,json_request,data):    
            for i in data['filters']:
                if i['type'] == 'pool':
                        start_date =  i['date'][0]
                        end_date = i['date'][1]
                return  (start_date, end_date)
```

Comment: This is not what classes are for.

Comment: So you want to map JSON to classes?

Comment: @RoadRunner yess

Comment: I think you are storing the name of the filter in the 'name' key, but you checking it in the 'type' key? it should be `if i['name'] == 'pool':`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

functions should be used here instead of classes but if you still want to go for classes:

```
class RequestClass:
    def __init__(self, _request):
        self.json_data = json.load(_request.get_json())


class FilterExtractor(RequestClass):
    def __init__(self, _request):
        super().__init__(_request)

    def get_dates(self, **filters):
        """
        Returns list of start date and end date of filters along with filter id based on the filter types supplied
        **filters : tuple of (filter type: value) e.g. name= 'pool'
                    multiple filter values can be applied, e.g. name='pool', type='str' 
        """
        filter_dates = []
        for _filter in self.json_data['filters']:
            found = False
            for key, value in filters.items():
                if _filter[key] == value:
                    found = True
            if found:
                filter_dates.append((_filter['id'], _filter['date'][0], _filter['date'][1]))
        return filter_dates


@app.route('/out/', methods=['POST'])
def values_extract():
    fe = FilterExtractor(request)
    filter_dates = fe.get_dates(name="pool")
    return filter_dates


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: The program fits the needs. Just to add some description.

There should be a single responsibility for every class. In your case, you can use a `RequestManger` class to delegate all the serialization/deserialization work and another class to apply any business logic. 

SOLID: https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design

Answer (score 3):

Before jumping into the solution. You will need to ask yourself why do you need class? There is no need to keep a state for your use case. Even if you use class, there will be `@staticmethod` all over the place.

A straight forward refactor idea will be separating the data ser/deser logic and business logic. For your case

```py
import json

from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


def select_dates(data):
    start_date = ''
    end_date = ''
    for i in data['filters']:
        if i['type'] == 'pool':
            start_date = i['date'][0]
            end_date = i['date'][1]
    return [start_date, end_date]


@app.route('/out', methods=['POST'])
def values_extract():
    data = request.json
    # if valid json then do the below program in separate `**class**`
    return json.dumps(select_dates(data))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Also removed unnecessary json load/dump call.

HTTP is by natural stateless, you will find few use cases where class is necessary. Use function as much as you can.